# How does rust collect() create different collections generically

Tags: rust

According to the documentation, this method https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect can create different collections based on the type of the variable its return value is assigned to. I've been researching this for a while now and I can't find the key reason it's able to do this. Is it overloaded generically somehow? How is it able to create different types based on the variable type?

**I understand type inference is playing a role here, *but I'm more confused about how that works in tandem with the actual underlying implementation of `collect()`***

I'm beginning to learn rust so this concept is new to me. I am reading the rust book and have searched for this, but can't find what I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance!

Example from the link:

```
// This

let a = [1, 2, 3];

let doubled: Vec<i32> = a.iter()
                         .map(|&x| x * 2)
                         .collect();

assert_eq!(vec![2, 4, 6], doubled);

// Compared to this

use std::collections::VecDeque;

let a = [1, 2, 3];

let doubled: VecDeque<i32> = a.iter().map(|&x| x * 2).collect();

assert_eq!(2, doubled[0]);
assert_eq!(4, doubled[1]);
assert_eq!(6, doubled[2]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the generic type parameter of the [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) method implements the [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) trait. This is where all the magic happens -- if you look at the [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#1744-1746) of `Iterator::collect<B>`, you'll see that all it does is call `FromIterator::from_iter`. Since the compiler expects the return value to be of type `B`, it infers that `FromIterator::from_iter` refers to the implementation of `FromIterator::from_iter` on `B` (as `from_iter` returns `Self`).

If you look at [implementors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#implementors) of `FromIterator`, you'll see that many standard collection types (among other types) like `Vec` and `VecDeque` implement this trait, and hence can be `collect`ed into. To put everything together, when compiling the line of code

```
let v: Vec<_> = some_iterator.collect()
```

The compiler first sets the type parameter `B` of the `collect` method to be `Vec<_>` (since `collect` returns a `B`), then calls the [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E-6) of `FromIterator::from_iter` for `Vec<T>` in the function body of `Iterator::collect` to collect `some_iterator` into a `Vec`.

Comment: Ty! I think I understand, but I'm a little confused with the pattern of calling the trait method against the trait itself. Does this pattern have a name?

Comment: I'm guessing it's just an associated function like anything else, but on a trait

Comment: That is correct. In the context of the implementation of `collect`, `B::from_iter`, `FromIterator::from_iter` and `<B as FromIterator>::from_iter` are the same thing (the first two desugar to the latter after type inference) -- each refers to the `from_iter` function implemented via the `FromIterator` trait for the type `B`. I prefer writing `B::from_iter` as it makes explicit _which_ type `from_iter` is being called on, but all three approaches are equivalent in the eyes of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`collect` is a generic function:

```
fn collect<B>(self) -> B where ...
```

The return type depends on the generic type parameter. Any specialization, with that type parameter specified, will return a fixed type. The specialization `collect::<Vec<i32>>` will return `Vec<i32>`.

The implementation is essentially an indirection:

```
fn collect<B>(self) -> B
where
    B: FromIterator<Self::Item>,
    Self: Sized
{
    FromIterator::from_iter(self)
}
```

The type `B` is required to be something that can be constructed from an iterator, using `FromIterator`. Many containers would fit that requirement. We have an iterator type, `Self`. So, the implementation just delegates to `FromIterator`. For the implementation, `B` is an abstract type parameter, and what we know about it is exactly the constraints we specify.

For the code in question:

```
let doubled: Vec<i32> = a.iter()
                         .map(|&x| x * 2)
                         .collect();
```

`collect` is not given its type parameter, so it must be inferred. Note that the implementation does not act in tandem, per se. The type must be chosen before the body is instantiated.

It is known from the signature of `collect` that the type parameter and the return type are equal. The result is assigned to `doubled`, so the type of `doubled` and the return type of `collect` are equal. The type of `doubled` is specified. Therefore, the type parameter to `collect` is that type.

For comparison, in a language like C++ one could write:

```
 template <typename Container, typename Iterator>
 auto collect(Iterator begin, Iterator end) -> Container
 {
     return Container(begin, end);
 }

 auto s = std::string("foo");
 auto v = collect<std::vector<char>>(s.begin(), s.end());
```

A salient difference is that C++'s type inference is less powerful. Types can be deduced from parameters, like `Iterator`, but other types cannot be deduced and must be specified, like `Container`.